# JSDoc ignores some functions

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have functions in this style:

```
/**
 * Here is my jsdoc comment
 */
Controller.add = function(req, res, next){}
```

My problem is that jsdoc ignores this comments. I just get a documentation for functions like this:

```
/**
 * Here is my jsdoc comment (which works fine)
 */
 function add(req, res, next){}
```

Do I miss a configuration? The documentation [doc](http://usejsdoc.org/) doesn't give me useful information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in your comment a `@alias`
In your example 
  
   `/**
    * Here is my jsdoc comment
    * @alias add
   */`

Comment: I think if you just add @namespace in the comment of your Controller. It will work as well